# I can't return the value of an Enum? An exception is thrown, why?

Tags: java, exception, enums

I am finding some difficulties work on this class (not written by me),  post only the section of the class that is affected by the problem:

```
public class Drive {
    .........................
    .........................
    public enum DriveMode {
    None, Stub, Mirror
    };
    .........................
    .........................

    public String getModeString() {
        return mode.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

The problm is that when, from another class, I try to call the **getModeString()** method it give me an error (throw an exception)

Infact into another class I call:

```
if(drive.getModeString() != null)
    driveElement.getChild("mode").setText(drive.getModeString());
```

and using the debug I see that it go in error when it call **drive.getModeString()**, then try to execute **return mode.toString().toLowerCase();** but:

1) If, into debugger, I try to evaluate the expression **mode.toString().toLowerCase()** it say to me that: `<error(s)_during_the_evaluation>` and if I proceed with debugging going to the next step a NullPointerException is thrown

Why? Someone have some ideas about how to solve it?

Tnx
Andrea

Comment: You don't show where "mode" data member is declared or assigned.  It is most likely null.

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't included enough details. Where the mode is declared and populated? What's the exact exception and stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `mode` field is just null.

Comment: I thought that it was initialized with the first value (None) by default if mode field was not explicitelly initialized, is it not?

Comment: @AndreaNobili No, you need explicitly initilize the field just like with any other non-primitive type or it will be null. Do something like `private DriveMode mode = DriveMode.NONE;`